# Changing default shell in Linux Mint

Tags: shell, linux-mint

Using `chsh` I can change my login shell. However, how do I change my non-login shell? I am using Linux Mint with Cinnamon desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer [on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/342299):

Cinnamon uses `gnome-terminal` and one must edit their profile to run any other shell than the default (bash).

Comment: Hi @Merik how do you edit your profile is that in the menu. I couldn't find mines I've upgraded my OS a few times, I'm not sure if I'm missing a few things that a new install would have by default.